# Посчитать, сколько в списке из случайных чисел существует таких, которые имеют четные десятки

Tags: python, list, range

Прохожу тему "списки". При решении одной из задач возникла проблема. Нужно из какого-то количества случайных чисел посчитать, сколько из них имеют четный десяток. Вроде код написал верно, случайные числа выводятся:

```
X, Y, N = map(int,input().split())
from random import randint
A = [randint(X,Y) for i in range(N)]
print(*A)
C = 0
for l in range(*A):
    if (l//10)%2 == 0:
        C = C + 1
    elif (l//10)%2 != 0:
        C = C + 0
    print(C)
```

Но второе условие выполняется только тогда, когда количество аргументов не превышает трех, при большем количестве чисел возникает такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 6, in <module>
    for l in range(*A):
TypeError: range expected at most 3 arguments, got 50
```

объясните пожалуйста, **почему так?**

Comment: Возвращайся к теме Циклы.

Comment: Импорты по правилам полагается располагать _в начале_ программы.

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка в вызове **range()**. Функция может принимать на вход 3 параметра(старт, стоп, шаг), в то время, как `*A` передает все элементы списка как отдельные аргументы.

> Если `A = [1, 2, 3, 4]`, то `range(*A)` будет выглядеть так: `range(1, 2, 3, 4)`

Вместо `range(*A)` укажите `A`

```
from random import randint

X, Y, N = map(int,input().split())

A = [randint(X,Y) for i in range(N)]
print(*A)
C = 0
for l in A: # <- тут
    if (l//10)%2 == 0:
        C = C + 1
    elif (l//10)%2 != 0:
        C = C + 0
print(C)
```

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка возникает в строке `for l in range(*A):`, т.к. вы передаете в функцию `range()` в качестве аргументов распакованный список `A`. Так, если, например, `A = [12,5,7,15]`, то `range(*A)` будет выглядеть после распаковки так: `range(12,5,7,15)`. В свою очередь, функция `range()` принимает максимум 3 аргумента - начальное значение, конечное значение и шаг. А когда вы передаете больше трех аргументов (в вашем случае - 50), возникает ошибка. Вам нужно перебирать просто список `A`, функция `range()` здесь не нужна:

```
for l in A:
```